# node-storage close a storage and save changes before creating a new storage

Tags: node.js

I am using [node-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-storage) in the following code to store a value in a file, however when I create a new storage object changes from another storage object are not yet saved. I need a way to save the changes before creating the new storage object.

Below is a program called code.js which I am running like so in the console: `node code.js`. If you run it you will see that the first time it is run the key value pair doesn't yet exist however it does exist the second time.

```
key = "key"

storage = require('node-storage')

const store1 = new storage("file")
const store2 = new storage("file")

store1.put(key,'val')

console.log(store2.get(key))
```

My motivation for this is that I want to be able to have a function called "set" which takes a key and a value and sets the key value pair in a dictionary of values that is store in a file. I want to be able to refer to this dictionary later, with for example a 'get' function, and have the changes present.

I am thinking there might be a function called "save" or something similar that applies the changes to the file. Is there such a function or some other solution?

Comment: The only possible solution I see is to use `_load()` (`store2._load()`) function before accessing `store2.get(key)` to refresh `store2` object values from file.

Comment: Based on [source code](https://github.com/amativos/node-storage/blob/master/index.js): When you create a new store object (`new storage('file')`) it loads current content from 'file' into memory (`store2.store` property in your case). If you modify the content of 'file' manually or using another store object (`store1` in your case) it does not refresh in-memory content of `store2`, so you need to manually refresh the state of `store2` object by calling `store2._load()`

Comment: You can either use the  Ihor Sakaylyuk's comment or you can just write your own functions to read and write from a file according to your need.That would be the best suggestion from my side.You can  just use REDIS if you want key value kind of store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

node-storage saves the changes in the dictionary to disk after every call to `put` or `remove`. This is not the issue.

Your problem is that the dictionary in `store2` has not been updated with the new properties. node-storage only loads the file from disk when the object is first created.

My suggestion would be to only have one instance of storage per file.

However, if this is not possible, then you might want to consider updating `store2`'s cache before you get the property. This can be done using:

```
store2.store = store2._load();
```

This may not be the best for performance, as `_load` loads the entire file from disk *synchronously* every time it is called, so try to limit its use.